# How can I return multiple performance counters with Get-Counter at one time?

Tags: windows, performance, powershell

I can't figure out how to record multiple metrics from the system using a list. The `$CounterList` var doesn't work but the `$CounterList_Working` var does. I've seen examples that are getting a list based on the paths such as `(Get-Counter -List Processor(*)).Paths`.

I thought I could specify the paths in a variable but that doesn't work.

What is wrong with the `$CounterList` in the PowerShell script? The error message I get is "Get-Counter : The specified object was not found on the computer.". Which makes me think it's trying to read the list as a single value.

```
$CounterList = "\Network Interface(*)\Packets/sec
\Network Interface(*)\Current Bandwidth
\Network Interface(*)\Bytes Total/sec
\Memory\Committed Bytes
\Memory\Commit Limit"

$CounterList_Working = "\Processor(*)\% Processor Time"

echo "Gathering system data and writing to file $home\system_metrics.blg"
Get-Counter -Counter $CounterList -SampleInterval 2 -MaxSamples 10 | Export-counter -Path $home\system_metrics.blg
```

Comment: Your `$CounterList` is just a single string, not an array of strings. Compare to `$arr = 'str1', 'str2', 'str3'` - there are many ways to declare an array properly, you may want to look that up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [MSDN for Get-Counter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-counter), the parameter ...

> **-Counter**
>
> Specifies, as a string *array*, data from the specified performance counters. Enter one or more counter paths. You can also pipe counter path strings to this cmdlet.

You are using a single string which would be fine for a single counter. You need an array for your list of multiple counters.

```
$CounterList = "\Network Interface(*)\Packets/sec",
    "\Network Interface(*)\Current Bandwidth",
    "\Network Interface(*)\Bytes Total/sec",
    "\Memory\Committed Bytes",
    "\Memory\Commit Limit"
```

Should do the trick as would many other ways to declare a string array.

If for some crazy reason you are really working with a newline delimited string you could just convert that to a string array with a `-split`. The following would give you the same results as my first example.

```
$CounterList = "\Network Interface(*)\Packets/sec
    \Network Interface(*)\Current Bandwidth
    \Network Interface(*)\Bytes Total/sec
    \Memory\Committed Bytes
    \Memory\Commit Limit" -split "`r`n"
```

However if you have any control over this I would opt for the former declaration.

Comment: Thanks that was what I was missing.